# How to use Logout endpoint in Spring Authorization Server 1.1.0

Tags: openid-connect, logout, spring-authorization-server

I tried this code to invalidate the session but nothing works , the session still valid and i can't logout :

```
  axiosInstance
            .post(
                'http://192.168.1.11:9000/connect/logout',
                {
                    id_token_hint: idToken,
                    client_id: OAuth2.clientId,
                },
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    },
                }
            )
```